# What is a circular reference and a loop?

Tags: asp.net

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentsController : ApiController
{
    public Department Get(int id)
    {
        Department sales = new Department() { Name = "Sales" };
        Employee alice = new Employee() { Name = "Alice", Department = sales };
        sales.Manager = alice;
        return sales;
    }
}
```

The controller action will return this JSON (after changing settings to preserve object references)

```
{  
   "$id":"1",
   "Name":"Sales",
   "Manager":{  
      "$id":"2",
      "Name":"Alice",
      "Department":{  
         "$ref":"1"
      }
   }
}
```

Apparently the `Employee.Department`  property creates a loop and why is it a problem? What exactly is this loop? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because it is literally a circular loop. A department points to a single employee, which points back to the same department, which points back to the same employee, which points back to the same department... You see what I'm getting at here. Serializing a `Department` would result in a string with **infinite length**.

If you simply set `alice.Department = null` it should resolve the endless loop. And since you already know `sales.Manager = alice` there is essentially no irretrievable data.

Answer (score 0):

Because an employee has a department, and a department has an employee. That is a circular dependency. Each requires a definition of the other.

For example: Bob - > Electrical - > Steve - > Homewares - > Bob...